# Can't save on disk a database with sqlite3 - Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, heroku, disk

I'm using sqlite3 (*import sqlite3*) with python, but i'm not able to save the db file on the disk (in my case on heroku, inside */app/*). No errors when i run this:

```
c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE users (userid int, isbot boolean);')
    c.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (000000000, 'test');")
    c.commit()

    c2 = sqlite3.connect('/app/bot.db')
    with c2:
      for line in c.iterdump():
        if line not in ('BEGIN;', 'COMMIT;'): # let python handle the transactions
          c2.execute(line)
    c2.commit()
```

Comment: SQLite is incompatible with Heroku. This is well documented, both [in official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) and [in questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku+sqlite). You'll have to migrate to a real client-server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe heroku supports this type of file

Found this on their site.

Disk backed storage
SQLite runs in memory, and backs up its data store in files on disk. While this strategy works well for development, Heroku’s Cedar stack has an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it, and you can read from it, but the contents will be cleared periodically. If you were to use SQLite on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least once every 24 hours.

Even if Heroku’s disks were persistent running SQLite would still not be a good fit. Since SQLite does not run as a service, each dyno would run a separate running copy. Each of these copies need their own disk backed store. This would mean that each dyno powering your app would have a different set of data since the disks are not synchronized.

Instead of using SQLite on Heroku you can configure your app to run on Postgres.

Comment: Thanks, i will go with Postgres!